# Add database add-in in Monodevelop 2.2.2 on Windows?

Tags: windows, database, repository, add-in, monodevelop

I have the problem I just installed the new Monodevelop 2.2.2 on Windows but I haven't the database add-in and I cannot add-in with the basic repository.

Are-there other repository for that ?

Thanks with advance.

Narglix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database add-in is probably no longer available, however in version 2.6 is planned [new one](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Tasks/Tools/Database_Add-in).

Comment: But I don't understand why the version of Linux had it and not the Windows version ?

Comment: That's question for developers, but future seems promising.